# How can I make a pygame mouse clicking event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to add 1 to the variable i when I click the image in pygame.
How can I do it?

```
if : #code:
    i += 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask around the image, and detect when the coordinate of the cursor is inside the image. Then, add 1 to the counter. (`x` in this case):

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
img = pygame.image.load('img.jpeg').convert_alpha() # Your image here
img_pos = (100, 100) # Adjust position of image
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(img)
x = 0
while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.quit()
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            try:
                if mask.get_at((e.pos[0]-img_pos[0], e.pos[1]-img_pos[1])):
                    x += 1
                    print(x)
            except IndexError:
                pass

    screen.fill((80,80,80))
    screen.blit(img, img_pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This should work with your image, just load your image instead of `img.jpeg`, and set your coordinates of the image correctly. Here is the image I worked with for reference:

[image]